# variably modified type in char[]

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arrays

I have this struct. What I am trying to do is to have a continues ram space to memcpy them on hard drive. I have a dynamic created string which I will use as a key. I want to create a struct that can do this. I used templates and I made this.

```
template <class ItemType> struct INXM_Node {
    ItemType key;
    int left;
    int right;
    int next; // Used for queue.
} ;
```

I was running:

```
INXM_Node<char[100]> *root = new INXM_Node<char[100]>();
```

Everything was fine until I tried to change **100** with a variable. Then i got error:

```
'char [(((long unsigned int)(((long int)attrLength) - 1)) + 1u)]' is a variably modified type
```

What I ran was:

```
sizeof(INXM_Node<char[attrLength]>);
```

I am taking **attrLength** as an argument from a function.
I need to generate multiple structs with different char arrays.

Comment: I removed the C tag because of the keywords `class`, `template` and `new`

Comment: Types have to be known at compile time. That means that array types can only be formed with **compile-time known sizes**. Your design approach should probably be reworked, why don't you post your goals?

Answer (score 1):

The type you use to instantiate a template *must* be fixed at compile time. When you compile with a template, specific code is emitted by the compiler, for the different types you use with the template. This can't be done at run time (there might not be a compiler available even) and it would be unreasonable and indeed impossible to expect it to be done for every possible type at compile time.

I think you're taking the wrong approach to your problem in general though. It would be better to use `std::string` as the key if you need the size to vary at run time and use something like [boost::serialize](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) to (portably and safely) save your data to disk.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler needs to know what type `ItemType` is at compile time. When you use a variable, it cannot know. The compiler attempts to specifically create each `ItemType` that will be used in the execution of your program.  If you are using a variable length `char` array, the compiler does not know how much memory to allocate for that particular `ItemType`. You might consider using `std::string`